# Angular + .Net Core WebApi print labels on Zebra printer

Tags: c#, angular, printing, zebra-printers

we have an Angular application to create a list of addresses. These addreses have to be printed out on an Zebra label printer ZDesigner GK420t.

I first thought of the `document.print()` function, but that's impossible to format for the printer.

So I think there should be a server side way to do it. I found this example [here](https://www.neodynamic.com/articles/How-to-print-raw-Zebra-ZPL-commands-from-ASP-NET-directly-to-the-client-printer/) but with this it's required to have WebClientPrint Processor to be installed...

The printer is available in the company network and the server side application is hosted in the same network. Is there another way that the server can send an print task directly to the printer or something like this?

Answer (score 0):

The way we handle printing from our web app is to have an iframe that is not directly visible on the page. Then set the src to a nicely formatted html page.

```
<iframe src="" style="position: absolute; top: -1000px;" id="printFrame" name="printFrame"></iframe>
```

That page should include a document ready event to start the print process:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        setTimeout(function () {
            window.parent.frames["printFrame"].focus();
            window.parent.frames["printFrame"].print();
        }, 1);

    });
```

This will then popup the default browser print dialog, ready for printing to the label printer.